# XML Data Binding Wizard doesn't bind XSD's correctly

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Simple issue, actually. Just curious if others recognize the problem and perhaps have a working solution for it...

I have a simple XSD file which I use to define a configuration file that is used by my application. I need to bind this schema to my project and this is done using the XDBW. In Delphi 2007, this wizard would just recognise an XSD as a schema and thus I would get perfect code for my schema.
I recently upgraded to Delphi XE and I want to recreate this code again, just for the fun of it. I could use the old code, so no problem there. I just want to see if D-XE had added some improvements.
Unfortunately, D-XE interprets the file just like any other file and generates code that would help me to create this schema from code. CLANK! (That's the sound of my head hitting a wall...) I don't want that! I want code to generate the XML that is described by the schema!
So, is this problem familiar for other users? Any solutions yet?

---

One solution is to just use the D2007 source files. That's not an answer, though, since I need to do this exclusively from D-XE.

---

Another solution is by renaming the xsd file to an .biz extension. But this is an extremely ugly hack...

Comment: Can you please mail me that xsd file? Almost anything at pluimers dot com will do, especially when it includes my first name.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I've tried over a dozen of different XSD's, including some very basic ones with just one root element and nothing else. It interprets it as XML, not as an XSD. (It does interpret .biz files as XSD's though...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in Delphi XE.
It is now in the Embarcadero bug tracking system as entry [88893](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88893)

I tried importing the ASX.XSD file below in Rad Studio XE using the XML Data Binding Wizard, and it just works like you describe: it imports the XSD as if it were XML in stead of XSD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="asx" type="asxType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="asxType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="entry" type="entryType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:decimal" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="entryType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="ref" type="refType" />
      <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="refType">
    <xsd:attribute name="href" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

It gets me this unit:

```
{*****************************************************************************************************}
{                                                                                                     }
{                                          XML Data Binding                                           }
{                                                                                                     }
{         Generated on: 10/12/2010 9:41:06 PM                                                         }
{       Generated from: C:\develop\codeplex\TFS05\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\NederlandFM2WMP\doc\ASX.xsd   }
{   Settings stored in: C:\develop\codeplex\TFS05\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\NederlandFM2WMP\doc\ASX.xdb   }
{                                                                                                     }
{*****************************************************************************************************}

unit ASX;

interface

uses xmldom, XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

type

{ Forward Decls }

  IXMLSchemaType = interface;
  IXMLElementType = interface;
  IXMLComplexType = interface;
  IXMLComplexTypeList = interface;
  IXMLSequenceType = interface;
  IXMLAttributeType = interface;

{ IXMLSchemaType }

  IXMLSchemaType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{F8A90A02-2236-4A50-A278-CFBB8625B36C}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_AttributeFormDefault: UnicodeString;
    function Get_ElementFormDefault: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Version: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Element: IXMLElementType;
    function Get_ComplexType: IXMLComplexTypeList;
    procedure Set_AttributeFormDefault(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_ElementFormDefault(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Version(Value: UnicodeString);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property AttributeFormDefault: UnicodeString read Get_AttributeFormDefault write Set_AttributeFormDefault;
    property ElementFormDefault: UnicodeString read Get_ElementFormDefault write Set_ElementFormDefault;
    property Version: UnicodeString read Get_Version write Set_Version;
    property Element: IXMLElementType read Get_Element;
    property ComplexType: IXMLComplexTypeList read Get_ComplexType;
  end;

{ IXMLElementType }

  IXMLElementType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{9AAD80FD-06BC-4F82-9321-538F05522F83}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Name: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Type_: UnicodeString;
    function Get_MaxOccurs: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Type_(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_MaxOccurs(Value: UnicodeString);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Name: UnicodeString read Get_Name write Set_Name;
    property Type_: UnicodeString read Get_Type_ write Set_Type_;
    property MaxOccurs: UnicodeString read Get_MaxOccurs write Set_MaxOccurs;
  end;

{ IXMLComplexType }

  IXMLComplexType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{9C0618C5-D81F-4BB5-8DED-0BF9AF757ABD}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Name: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Sequence: IXMLSequenceType;
    function Get_Attribute: IXMLAttributeType;
    procedure Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Name: UnicodeString read Get_Name write Set_Name;
    property Sequence: IXMLSequenceType read Get_Sequence;
    property Attribute: IXMLAttributeType read Get_Attribute;
  end;

{ IXMLComplexTypeList }

  IXMLComplexTypeList = interface(IXMLNodeCollection)
    ['{26C4DF98-1DCA-44C8-9D58-9BEB9348FA5B}']
    { Methods & Properties }
    function Add: IXMLComplexType;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLComplexType;

    function Get_Item(Index: Integer): IXMLComplexType;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: IXMLComplexType read Get_Item; default;
  end;

{ IXMLSequenceType }

  IXMLSequenceType = interface(IXMLNodeCollection)
    ['{9289143E-C0E2-462E-AD77-239966EEAEEC}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Element(Index: Integer): IXMLElementType;
    { Methods & Properties }
    function Add: IXMLElementType;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLElementType;
    property Element[Index: Integer]: IXMLElementType read Get_Element; default;
  end;

{ IXMLAttributeType }

  IXMLAttributeType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{409542A8-7FB2-4C90-BE41-C081A0518773}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Name: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Type_: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Type_(Value: UnicodeString);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Name: UnicodeString read Get_Name write Set_Name;
    property Type_: UnicodeString read Get_Type_ write Set_Type_;
  end;

{ Forward Decls }

  TXMLSchemaType = class;
  TXMLElementType = class;
  TXMLComplexType = class;
  TXMLComplexTypeList = class;
  TXMLSequenceType = class;
  TXMLAttributeType = class;

{ TXMLSchemaType }

  TXMLSchemaType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLSchemaType)
  private
    FComplexType: IXMLComplexTypeList;
  protected
    { IXMLSchemaType }
    function Get_AttributeFormDefault: UnicodeString;
    function Get_ElementFormDefault: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Version: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Element: IXMLElementType;
    function Get_ComplexType: IXMLComplexTypeList;
    procedure Set_AttributeFormDefault(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_ElementFormDefault(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Version(Value: UnicodeString);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

{ TXMLElementType }

  TXMLElementType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLElementType)
  protected
    { IXMLElementType }
    function Get_Name: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Type_: UnicodeString;
    function Get_MaxOccurs: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Type_(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_MaxOccurs(Value: UnicodeString);
  end;

{ TXMLComplexType }

  TXMLComplexType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLComplexType)
  protected
    { IXMLComplexType }
    function Get_Name: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Sequence: IXMLSequenceType;
    function Get_Attribute: IXMLAttributeType;
    procedure Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

{ TXMLComplexTypeList }

  TXMLComplexTypeList = class(TXMLNodeCollection, IXMLComplexTypeList)
  protected
    { IXMLComplexTypeList }
    function Add: IXMLComplexType;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLComplexType;

    function Get_Item(Index: Integer): IXMLComplexType;
  end;

{ TXMLSequenceType }

  TXMLSequenceType = class(TXMLNodeCollection, IXMLSequenceType)
  protected
    { IXMLSequenceType }
    function Get_Element(Index: Integer): IXMLElementType;
    function Add: IXMLElementType;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLElementType;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

{ TXMLAttributeType }

  TXMLAttributeType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLAttributeType)
  protected
    { IXMLAttributeType }
    function Get_Name: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Type_: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Type_(Value: UnicodeString);
  end;

{ Global Functions }

function Getschema(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLSchemaType;
function Loadschema(const FileName: string): IXMLSchemaType;
function Newschema: IXMLSchemaType;

const
  TargetNamespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';

implementation

{ Global Functions }

function Getschema(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLSchemaType;
begin
  Result := Doc.GetDocBinding('schema', TXMLSchemaType, TargetNamespace) as IXMLSchemaType;
end;

function Loadschema(const FileName: string): IXMLSchemaType;
begin
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName).GetDocBinding('schema', TXMLSchemaType, TargetNamespace) as IXMLSchemaType;
end;

function Newschema: IXMLSchemaType;
begin
  Result := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('schema', TXMLSchemaType, TargetNamespace) as IXMLSchemaType;
end;

{ TXMLSchemaType }

procedure TXMLSchemaType.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('element', TXMLElementType);
  RegisterChildNode('complexType', TXMLComplexType);
  FComplexType := CreateCollection(TXMLComplexTypeList, IXMLComplexType, 'complexType') as IXMLComplexTypeList;
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLSchemaType.Get_AttributeFormDefault: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['attributeFormDefault'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLSchemaType.Set_AttributeFormDefault(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('attributeFormDefault', Value);
end;

function TXMLSchemaType.Get_ElementFormDefault: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['elementFormDefault'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLSchemaType.Set_ElementFormDefault(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('elementFormDefault', Value);
end;

function TXMLSchemaType.Get_Version: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['version'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLSchemaType.Set_Version(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('version', Value);
end;

function TXMLSchemaType.Get_Element: IXMLElementType;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['element'] as IXMLElementType;
end;

function TXMLSchemaType.Get_ComplexType: IXMLComplexTypeList;
begin
  Result := FComplexType;
end;

{ TXMLElementType }

function TXMLElementType.Get_Name: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['name'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLElementType.Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('name', Value);
end;

function TXMLElementType.Get_Type_: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['type'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLElementType.Set_Type_(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('type', Value);
end;

function TXMLElementType.Get_MaxOccurs: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['maxOccurs'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLElementType.Set_MaxOccurs(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('maxOccurs', Value);
end;

{ TXMLComplexType }

procedure TXMLComplexType.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('sequence', TXMLSequenceType);
  RegisterChildNode('attribute', TXMLAttributeType);
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLComplexType.Get_Name: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['name'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLComplexType.Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('name', Value);
end;

function TXMLComplexType.Get_Sequence: IXMLSequenceType;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['sequence'] as IXMLSequenceType;
end;

function TXMLComplexType.Get_Attribute: IXMLAttributeType;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['attribute'] as IXMLAttributeType;
end;

{ TXMLComplexTypeList }

function TXMLComplexTypeList.Add: IXMLComplexType;
begin
  Result := AddItem(-1) as IXMLComplexType;
end;

function TXMLComplexTypeList.Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLComplexType;
begin
  Result := AddItem(Index) as IXMLComplexType;
end;

function TXMLComplexTypeList.Get_Item(Index: Integer): IXMLComplexType;
begin
  Result := List[Index] as IXMLComplexType;
end;

{ TXMLSequenceType }

procedure TXMLSequenceType.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('element', TXMLElementType);
  ItemTag := 'element';
  ItemInterface := IXMLElementType;
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLSequenceType.Get_Element(Index: Integer): IXMLElementType;
begin
  Result := List[Index] as IXMLElementType;
end;

function TXMLSequenceType.Add: IXMLElementType;
begin
  Result := AddItem(-1) as IXMLElementType;
end;

function TXMLSequenceType.Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLElementType;
begin
  Result := AddItem(Index) as IXMLElementType;
end;

{ TXMLAttributeType }

function TXMLAttributeType.Get_Name: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['name'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLAttributeType.Set_Name(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('name', Value);
end;

function TXMLAttributeType.Get_Type_: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['type'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLAttributeType.Set_Type_(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('type', Value);
end;

end.
```

But when using the .BIZ extension, it generates the correct unit:

```
{*****************************************************************************************************}
{                                                                                                     }
{                                          XML Data Binding                                           }
{                                                                                                     }
{         Generated on: 10/12/2010 9:47:29 PM                                                         }
{       Generated from: C:\develop\codeplex\TFS05\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\NederlandFM2WMP\doc\ASX.biz   }
{   Settings stored in: C:\develop\codeplex\TFS05\bo\Native\Delphi\Apps\NederlandFM2WMP\doc\ASX.xdb   }
{                                                                                                     }
{*****************************************************************************************************}

unit ASXUnit;

interface

uses xmldom, XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

type

{ Forward Decls }

  IXMLAsxType = interface;
  IXMLEntryType = interface;
  IXMLEntryTypeList = interface;
  IXMLRefType = interface;

{ IXMLAsxType }

  IXMLAsxType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{491F413D-0118-47A0-A00E-1BB7FCAD96C2}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Version: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Title: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Entry: IXMLEntryTypeList;
    procedure Set_Version(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Title(Value: UnicodeString);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Version: UnicodeString read Get_Version write Set_Version;
    property Title: UnicodeString read Get_Title write Set_Title;
    property Entry: IXMLEntryTypeList read Get_Entry;
  end;

{ IXMLEntryType }

  IXMLEntryType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{E1F7A8DC-0893-4853-BFFD-19D22AF3313C}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Title: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Ref: IXMLRefType;
    function Get_Author: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Title(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Author(Value: UnicodeString);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Title: UnicodeString read Get_Title write Set_Title;
    property Ref: IXMLRefType read Get_Ref;
    property Author: UnicodeString read Get_Author write Set_Author;
  end;

{ IXMLEntryTypeList }

  IXMLEntryTypeList = interface(IXMLNodeCollection)
    ['{4CA3727D-89DA-4498-B617-48D413D63887}']
    { Methods & Properties }
    function Add: IXMLEntryType;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLEntryType;

    function Get_Item(Index: Integer): IXMLEntryType;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: IXMLEntryType read Get_Item; default;
  end;

{ IXMLRefType }

  IXMLRefType = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{0860418C-E35A-4315-8B1C-7C0D19C45740}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Href: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Href(Value: UnicodeString);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Href: UnicodeString read Get_Href write Set_Href;
  end;

{ Forward Decls }

  TXMLAsxType = class;
  TXMLEntryType = class;
  TXMLEntryTypeList = class;
  TXMLRefType = class;

{ TXMLAsxType }

  TXMLAsxType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLAsxType)
  private
    FEntry: IXMLEntryTypeList;
  protected
    { IXMLAsxType }
    function Get_Version: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Title: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Entry: IXMLEntryTypeList;
    procedure Set_Version(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Title(Value: UnicodeString);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

{ TXMLEntryType }

  TXMLEntryType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLEntryType)
  protected
    { IXMLEntryType }
    function Get_Title: UnicodeString;
    function Get_Ref: IXMLRefType;
    function Get_Author: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Title(Value: UnicodeString);
    procedure Set_Author(Value: UnicodeString);
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

{ TXMLEntryTypeList }

  TXMLEntryTypeList = class(TXMLNodeCollection, IXMLEntryTypeList)
  protected
    { IXMLEntryTypeList }
    function Add: IXMLEntryType;
    function Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLEntryType;

    function Get_Item(Index: Integer): IXMLEntryType;
  end;

{ TXMLRefType }

  TXMLRefType = class(TXMLNode, IXMLRefType)
  protected
    { IXMLRefType }
    function Get_Href: UnicodeString;
    procedure Set_Href(Value: UnicodeString);
  end;

{ Global Functions }

function Getasx(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLAsxType;
function Loadasx(const FileName: string): IXMLAsxType;
function Newasx: IXMLAsxType;

const
  TargetNamespace = '';

implementation

{ Global Functions }

function Getasx(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLAsxType;
begin
  Result := Doc.GetDocBinding('asx', TXMLAsxType, TargetNamespace) as IXMLAsxType;
end;

function Loadasx(const FileName: string): IXMLAsxType;
begin
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName).GetDocBinding('asx', TXMLAsxType, TargetNamespace) as IXMLAsxType;
end;

function Newasx: IXMLAsxType;
begin
  Result := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('asx', TXMLAsxType, TargetNamespace) as IXMLAsxType;
end;

{ TXMLAsxType }

procedure TXMLAsxType.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('entry', TXMLEntryType);
  FEntry := CreateCollection(TXMLEntryTypeList, IXMLEntryType, 'entry') as IXMLEntryTypeList;
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLAsxType.Get_Version: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['version'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLAsxType.Set_Version(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('version', Value);
end;

function TXMLAsxType.Get_Title: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['title'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLAsxType.Set_Title(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  ChildNodes['title'].NodeValue := Value;
end;

function TXMLAsxType.Get_Entry: IXMLEntryTypeList;
begin
  Result := FEntry;
end;

{ TXMLEntryType }

procedure TXMLEntryType.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('ref', TXMLRefType);
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLEntryType.Get_Title: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['title'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLEntryType.Set_Title(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  ChildNodes['title'].NodeValue := Value;
end;

function TXMLEntryType.Get_Ref: IXMLRefType;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['ref'] as IXMLRefType;
end;

function TXMLEntryType.Get_Author: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['author'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLEntryType.Set_Author(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  ChildNodes['author'].NodeValue := Value;
end;

{ TXMLEntryTypeList }

function TXMLEntryTypeList.Add: IXMLEntryType;
begin
  Result := AddItem(-1) as IXMLEntryType;
end;

function TXMLEntryTypeList.Insert(const Index: Integer): IXMLEntryType;
begin
  Result := AddItem(Index) as IXMLEntryType;
end;

function TXMLEntryTypeList.Get_Item(Index: Integer): IXMLEntryType;
begin
  Result := List[Index] as IXMLEntryType;
end;

{ TXMLRefType }

function TXMLRefType.Get_Href: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := AttributeNodes['href'].Text;
end;

procedure TXMLRefType.Set_Href(Value: UnicodeString);
begin
  SetAttribute('href', Value);
end;

end.
```

Bug: Will QC this soon.

Comment: Embarcadero just delived the first update for D-XE. It seems to have solved this annoying problem! :-)