# Are there alternate XML schema importers available for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, xsd

Importing complex XSDs can cause the Delphi XML Binding Wizard to crash.  I've reported it a few times over the last few years and now I'm looking for alternatives.

The latest two automated Quality Central reports generated when importing ProcessSalesLead schema from the StarStandard set of schemas.
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98391

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98392

Schemas are available online and are widely utilized in the automotive industry
http://www.starstandard.org/SIGXMLSTAR5/XMLSchemas

Comment: A similar question, [xml-data-binding-wizard-doesnt-bind-xsds-correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871221/xml-data-binding-wizard-doesnt-bind-xsds-correctly) talks about renaming the .xsd file to a .biz file before importing. It's referred to as an ugly hack.

Comment: I could not get access to any of the QC reports. So I tried to download the ProcessSalesLead.wsdl file and import it in my Delphi-XE2 IDE. No problems there.

Comment: Schema version 5.4.4?  Delphi XE2 Update 3?

Comment: Yes, 5.4.4 and XE2 update 3. I can post the converted file if you like.

Comment: Ah...you did the WSDL to end up with a TRemotable.  I was importing the XSD via the XML binding wizard

Comment: My bad, and the XML data binding wizard is not in my version. Sorry !

Comment: Well, if one can import it the other should be able to.  I imagine that they are both defining the structures of the objects...just pass the soap envelope to one and the xml doc to the other.  I didn't try the wsdl before - that could be a workaround.

Comment: Years later...still no love for complex XSD imports with Delphi.  Related comments on other sites as well.  https://jonlennartaasenden.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/delphi-xml-data-binding-pains/

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [XSDTool v.3.0.0.2](http://www.torry.net/vcl/vcltools/compound/XSDTool3.0.0.1xsdtool.zip) by [Thomas Kerkmann](http://thkerkmann.homeip.net/).