# Delphi XML Data Bindings error: "Unknown datatype"

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe

I'm trying to import an XSD file with some complex files from an imported schema. The XML Data Bindings Wizard gives me an "Unknown datatype" error. I see this problem mentioned in several forums but no solution in sight.

[This is the file](http://www.sii.cl/factura_electronica/schema_ic.zip) I'm trying to import. There are some other required files [here](http://www.sii.cl/factura_electronica/schema_dte.zip).

Is there any workaround or an alternate tool to generate XML classes for Delphi XE?

**Edit:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020386/are-there-alternate-xml-schema-importers-available-for-delphi) may be a duplicate of this, at least partially. Didn't found it the first time.

Comment: Having information required to understand your question somewhere else other than SO makes your question meaningless if that external site is down for some reason (or goes away). It's also not really a good idea to make people download unknown files in order to even know what you're asking. What specific datatype is it failing on? What is the full error text of the exception you're getting? Also, have you installed all updates for XE? There were [bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871221/xml-data-binding-wizard-doesnt-bind-xsds-correctly) related to data binding fixed in updates.

Comment: My hunch is that you have a one field that doesn't contain a value, even across all nodes, so the wizard doesn't understand the type. Make sure all fields have at least one value and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ken, appreciate your concern but the question is if there is a workaround for a _known_ problem or if there is an alternate tool for that. The error message is, even if you don't believe it, "unknown datatype." The links to the files are just for reference in the unlikely case somebody wants to check this by themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the XSD file contained the following:

```
    <xs:include schemaLocation="SiiTypes_v10.xsd"/>
```

This file contained several data type definitions that were in the same namespace than the current file. I'm not sure if this was the cause or simply that the wizard cannot include external files, but I just went ahead and put all the type definitions inside the file and it did the trick.

I have put the file in my source control system and I pray that this doesn't bite me in the tuckus in the near future.

I'll accept my own answer in a couple of days unless somebody knows a better way to make this work.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with the XML Data Bindings in delphi 7
If you use delphi 2010 there has been no such problem.

Comment: I'm using XE with the latest available patch.